# The `price` parameter should be the ID of a price object, rather than the literal numerical price

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameters, stripe-payments

I'm building an online store in rails and I have intergrated stripe to the app.

I'm getting the total price of items in a cart and passing it as a parameter to the controller:

```html
<div class="keep-shopping pv1 mt4 has-text-right">
  <%= link_to 'Keep Shopping', instruments_path, class: 'button is-warning' %>
</div>
<hr />
<section class="section">
  <%= render(@cart.line_items) %>

  <div class="columns">
    <div class="column">
      <%= button_to 'Empty Cart', @cart, method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure? " }, class: "button is-danger" %>
    </div>
    <div class="column total has-text-right">
      <h4 class="title is-4">
        <span class="f5 has-text-grey">Total:</span> <%= number_to_currency(@cart.total_price) %>
      </h4>
      <%= link_to 'Buy', {controller:"checkouts", action:"show", 
           my_param:number_to_currency(@cart.total_price) }%>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

In the controller, I'm passing the total price as a variable:

```
class CheckoutsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :authenticate_user!

    def show()
        amount = params[:my_param]
        current_user.set_payment_processor :stripe
        current_user.payment_processor.customer
        

        @checkout_session = Stripe::Checkout::Session.create({
            line_items: [{
              # Provide the exact Price ID (e.g. pr_1234) of the product you want to sell
              price: amount
            }],
            mode: 'payment',
            success_url:checkout_success_url
          })
    end 

    def success
    
    end 
end
```

When I click the buy button on the web application, I get this error:
`The`price`parameter should be the ID of a price object, rather than the literal numerical price. Please see https://stripe.com/docs/billing/prices-guide#create-prices for more information about how to set up price objects.`

I would like the price to be passed inside the line_items correctly

Comment: In that case what you're looking for is not price but rather [price_data](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-line_items-price_data).

Comment: I replaced the price with data_price and I get an error saying Invalid Object.

Comment: It is unclear how you are going about this but you need a "price ID". You could [search](https://stripe.com/docs/search#query-fields-for-prices) for it but it would be better to just pass it in which the request. Through the "Buy" link (which you have not shown any additional code for)

Comment: Did you pass a hash containing all the required fields or just a float or whatever number you get? Also `my_param:number_to_currency(@cart.total_price)` is a textbook example of how not to handle money in an application. That helper is meant for just displaying prices so you're creating potential rounding errors and you should be totallying the total on the server and not passing it as a parameter unless you want to let malicous users set their own pricing.

Comment: I have added the rest of the code for the view. What I'm trying to do is that I have created an online store and once a person adds items to the cart, the total price is shown to the user. I would like to display the total price on the stripe checkout page so the user can proceed to make a payment.

Comment: Are you creating an online store that has actual items in it? It sounds more like you just want people to pay through Stripe. Items in your store are objects and they have associated price objects. https://stripe.com/docs/products-prices/how-products-and-prices-work

Answer (score 1):

it's `price_data` not `data_price` and it's a hash not an amount. usually this is used if you don't want to create the prices/products on Stripe's end especially if you don't really have predefined prices/products and the amount is forever changing. The code would look like

````
line_items: [{ 
  price_data: { 
    currency: 'xxx', 
    product_data:{ 
      name: 'My product' 
    }, 
    unit_amount: amount
  } 
}]```
````